# How to get this lug off

Tags: wheels, lug-nut

My truck had these fancy lug nuts and I accidentally broke one off and I don't know how to get the remnants off. Any ideas?

[image: Here's a picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a bit of pipe as a protective collar and drill out the remnants of the nut.

If you have the tools then making a washer in the end of the pipe with guide holes for the drill would be better...

Remove one of the other nuts to see how much clearance there is...

On one of my wheels this had to be done and the cowboy who did it left drill marks on the wheel... But luckily the clamping force is on the flat face...

Comment: I didn't really know what you meant about using a pipe but I drilled it out. I initially got a solid eighth of the nut drilled away but it wouldn't come off and by then I figured I had knicked the stud a bunch so I just got a fresh bit and went to town on the stud. Now I need to replace the stud but I don't see anything else working.

Comment: Well done, the pipe was to slide into the hole in the wheel as a protective sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'd take a small cold chisel and split what's left of the nut. If careful, you should be able to do this without damaging the lug. If if you do end up damaging the lug, they usually aren't that hard to replace. I'm not seeing as how you are going to get around doing damaging something, though ... either rim or lug.

Answer (score 0):

I would buy, something like the following: [Here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007C6KKAK)

- Spray the nut with penetrating oil twice a day for a day or two then use that tool.
  Should come right off.